# Disable SSL redirect for Kubernetes NGINX ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

An SSL redirect is enabled by default in a Kubernetes NGINX ingress. How can this be disabled? Current implementation below:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: project_name-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: project_name
          servicePort: 80
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Adding `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"` to `annotations` will disable the SSL redirect:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: project_name-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: project_name
          servicePort: 80
```

Note that `false` is wrapped in quotation marks. I found it didn't work without this string casting.

Comment: there is just a typo to fix:
`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"`
instead of 
`ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"`